# Telerik MVC Ajax Grid won't expand on save

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm having a problem using the Telerik MVC Grid control. I want the control to expand the newly saved row (which always stands on top because the rows are sorted on time ) when the new row is saved.

I've used the following code for it in my grid:

```
@(Html.Telerik()
  .Grid<Models.ViewModels.BestellingModel>()
  .Name("...")
  .DetailView(
       ...
  )
  .DataBinding(
      db =>
          {
              db.Ajax().Select(...);
              db.Ajax().Update(...);
              db.Ajax().Insert(...);
              db.Ajax().Delete(...);
          }
  )
  .DataKeys(
      ...
  )
  .ToolBar(
      ...
  )
  .ClientEvents(e =>
                    {
                        e.OnError("onErrorGrid");
                        e.OnSave("onSaveBestelling");
                        e.OnDataBound("bestellingenVanKlant_onRowDataBound");
                    }
  )
)
```

and here is the javascript:

```
var isSaved = false;

function onSaveBestelling(e) {
    isSaved = true;
}

function bestellingenVanKlant_onRowDataBound(e) {
    if (isSaved) {
        var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
        grid.expandRow(0);

        isSaved = false;
    }     
}
```

When I track the code path using firebug, it shows the code is getting executed. In my view however, the row does not expand after inserting a new row.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your bestellingenVanKlant_onRowDataBound function:

```
var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
expandFirstRow(grid, e.row);
```

and use the expandFirstRow function:

```
function expandFirstRow(grid, row) {
    if (grid.$rows().index(row) == 0) {
        grid.expandRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not fix the error. By trying to pass the e.row to another function I did find out that e.row is an undefined variable. This seems very weird to me since the event should contain a row value.